# RegExp select values

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I've got the string variable, containing the folowing text:

```
var val1="GES3 02R202035   ";
var val2=0;
var val3="06              ";
var val4="03.01.11i";
var val5="";
```

I want to use RegExp to get the array of values and filter values from trailing spaces also.

`/="?([\w\s\.]*)/g` helps alot, except trailing spaces, and i'm not sure about other charachters there could be.
So I need something like `/="?(.*);/g` but it doesn't remove last `"` and spaces also.

`/="?(.*)"?;/g` doesn't remove last `"`, who know why?

Could please anybody help me with this?

Edit:

The expected output is:

```
GES3 02R202035
0
06
03.01.11i
and empty string here
```

Edit:

I need this in javascript (node.js) `str.match(/?????/);`

Edit: With the help of Wiktor Stribiżew and melpomene finally I came to:
(notice lookbehind in regex, it will work in chrome with harmony flag enabled only)

```js
var str =
    'var val1="GES3 02R202035   ";\n' +
    'var val2=0;\n' +
    'var val3="06              ";\n' +
    'var val4="03.01.11i";\n' +
    'var val5="";\n';

console.log('before:\n' + str);

var parts = str.match(/(?<=="?)[^"]*?(?=\s*"?;)/g);
  
console.log('parts\n', parts);
```

The problem `with str.match()` was that it return array of matches, and I actually need array of groups. The solution was to arrange RegEx to match exactly the result what I need. It became possible with the latest V8 and its support of lookbehind.

Comment: Which language/tool? Please add the expected output.

Comment: Use `/="?(.*?)\s*"?;/g` though 4 optional subpatterns on end do not look nice. It will be better to just split with newline, then with the first `=` and trim the results from unwanted chars.

Comment: thanks, its ok with all except trailing spaces, by the way, could you explain how ? helped with last " ?

Comment: this was about your comment before edit, `/="?(.*?)\s*"?;/g` successfully removed trailings (tested on regexr.com) but not in node.js

Comment: in google chrome browser, trailing spaces was not removed also, I consider your suggestion to do it without regex, thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Correct me if I wrong, but it will be good to use .trim() for removing spaces!

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew your regexp works absolutely correct both in node and in browser, I was wrong about str.match(), without /g it return matches and groups, and with /g only matches, so i see no way without additional code to work it out.

Comment: There is no problems with additional code, see the answer below, it shows how to iterate the matches and grab the captured part only.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str =
    'var val1="GES3 02R202035   ";\n' +
    'var val2=0;\n' +
    'var val3="06              ";\n' +
    'var val4="03.01.11i";\n' +
    'var val5="";\n';

console.log('before:\n' + str);

var re = /=\s*(?:([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|"([^"]*)")/g;

var parts = [];
var m;
while (m = re.exec(str)) {
    var x =
        m[1] !== undefined
            ? Number(m[1])
            : m[2].trim()
    parts.push(x);
}

console.log('parts\n', parts);
```

This code extracts the embedded numbers and strings (after a `=` sign). Numbers (in the format `(- | +)? digits (. digits)?`, i.e. an optional sign and optional decimal places are accepted) are converted to JS numbers; strings have their contents extracted and trimmed.

It does not support exponential notation (`1e2`) or backslash escapes in strings.

Comment: thanks for your compehensive answer, (the first one before edit I liked even more cause it was more precise and compact), but I had hope it is possible to peform with one line of str.match() the only problem it needs the relevant data to be as a match and not as group as I had expected